# Change and Load <select> mySQL values from another <select>

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select

I have two `<select>`, Categories and Subcategories. 
I want when i click an option/value from Categories then load & update the second `<select>` from mySQL. Subcategories values are in mySQL.

(1) Category Select

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="check()"  id="category" name="category">
    <option  value="cafe">Café</option>
    <option  value="bars-clubs">Bars-Clubs</option>
    <option  value="restaurants">Restaurants</option>
    <option  value="shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option  value="services">Services</option>
    <option  value="sducation">Education</option>
</select>
```

(2) Subcategory Select

```
<select class="form-control " id="SubCategory" name="subCategory">
    <?php include "server.php";

        $qyerry = "select * from " + [[FROM CATEGORY VALUE]]
        $result = mysql_query($qyerry);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value=''>" . $row{'name'} . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here is my Javascript Code to get the value of onchange value option

```
<script>
   function check(){
      var x = document.getElementById("category").value;
   }                                
</script>
```

Comment: Bro, you can't that by that way.

Comment: And what i have to do?

Comment: i'm trying to write an answer for you

Comment: The best way would be to use AJAX. And please, please, don't use `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated and removed sincs PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

To implement cascading comboboxes, you need to use one of the following methods:

- Submit your form when changing the parent combobox.

  this means that, on your first select, you'll need to have something like this :`<select class="form-control" onchange="location.replace('current?action=CategorySelectionChanged')"`. 
  And in your server side prepare a query and passe its results to client side.
- Use an XmlHttpRequest to get the child's content and parse it via Javascript.

  Again, you'll need to fire a change event,  that will call the server.I assume that you are using jQuery, so the writing will be via Ajax call.

  Please take a look on [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2021940.aspx?pure+Jquery+and+ajax+cascading+dropdown+lists).

Comment: Okay man.. thanks a lot!!

Comment: you re welcome, don't hesitate to ask if you re blocked!

Comment: Finally i did it. All Subcategories appearing from mySQL. But there is a problem. When i trying to print the value of each <option> sometimes the value is wrong. 

http://prnt.sc/db117k

In the photo as you can see, i click the ''Clinic" but printed the previous value "Hospital "

Comment: i am not sure to understand your problem now, do you have a problem with the click event on an option ?